# How to define variable in vue template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

**Problem**

I have the need to temporarily store the results of a method call in Vue templates. This is particularly common inside loops, where I cannot easily use computed properties.

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="vehicleType in vehicleTypes" :key="vehicleType">
    <h3>{{ vehicleType }}</h3>
    <div v-if="getVehicleTypeData(vehicleType)">
     {{ getVehicleTypeData(vehicleType).costPerMile }}<br>
     {{ getVehicleTypeData(vehicleType).costPerHour }}<br>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript snippet:**

```
getVehicleTypeData: function(vehicleType){
    let options = _.find(this.vehicleTypeOptions, (obj)=>{
      return obj.vehicleType==vehicleType;
    });

    return options;
}
```

To improve performance, I really need a variable to store the method call result.

What is the Vue way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A quick way to work around Vue's current shortcomings is to use scoping through v-for and a single loop. A hopefully explanatory example:

```
<v-list>
  <v-list-tile v-for="(module, idx) in modules">
    <template v-for="scope in [{ isLocked: someFunction(module)}]">
      <!-- any markup -->
      <v-list-tile-action v-if="scope.isLocked">
        <v-icon color="amber">lock</v-icon>
      </v-list-tile-action>
    </template>
  </v-list-tile>
</v-list>
```

The `<template>` element above does the trick. You call your function (`someFunction`) in a temporary size-1 array of objects, assign it to a property (`isLocked`), which in turn is assigned to a scoped variable (`scope`). You can now access whatever someFunction returns as many times as you like without sacrificing performance through `scope.isLocked`.

Answer (score 6):

Anywhere in template you can hack your code with **:set="VAART = 12"** and magically the VAART variable will be set(but not will be reactive)

Tested this magic trick on VUE 3

Comment: Just want to add that `:set` is not a special prop, any prop name could be used that is not already in use. `:aaa` should work too. And this line needs to come before any props on the same element that need the assigned variable (important to know if you're using the vue/attributes-order eslint rule or anything else that would alphabetize props)

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a computed property which merges the type obj into the vehiclesTypes array.

```
computed: {

  vehicles() {
    return this.vehicleTypes.map(vehicle => {
       return {
         value: vehicle,
         type: { ...this.getVehicleTypeData(vehicle) }
       }
    })
  }

},

methods: {
  getVehicleTypeData(vehicleType){
    let options = _.find(this.vehicleTypeOptions, (obj)=>{
      return obj.vehicleType==vehicleType;
    });

    return options;
  }
}
```

And you can do:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="vehicle of vehicles" :key="vehicle.value">
    <h3>{{ vehicle.value }}</h3>
    <div v-if="vehicle.type">
     {{ vehicle.type.costPerMile }}<br>
     {{ vehicle.type.costPerHour }}<br>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you follow the logic I am sure it will work. Though I don't know the values of vehiclesTypes so the code above it may need some changes.

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to define a component. You can pass the value you need to "store" to it as a prop, and it can use it multiple ways. This is the more Vue-ish approach.

Another option is to wrap your function call in an array and use `v-for` to create an alias for it. This is more of a hacky/lazy optimization, but it's not brittle, just odd to read.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    vehicleTypes: [0, 1]
  },
  methods: {
    getVehicleTypeData(type) {
      return [{
        costPerMile: 10,
        costPerHour: 40
      }][type];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<ul id="app" new>
  <li v-for="vehicleType in vehicleTypes" :key="vehicleType">
    <h3>{{ vehicleType }}</h3>
    <template v-for="data in [getVehicleTypeData(vehicleType)]">
      <div v-if="data">
       {{ data.costPerMile }}<br> {{ data.costPerHour }}<br>
      </div>
    </template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution from some research, and I post answer myself, but not sure if there are any other best solutions.

**Javascript snippet:**

```
const Pass = {
  render() {
    return this.$scopedSlots.default(this.$attrs)
  }
}

export default {
  components: {
    Pass
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      vehicleTypeOptions: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getVehicleData: function(vehicleType){
      let option = _.find(this.vehicleTypeOptions, (obj)=>{
        return obj.vehicleType==vehicleType;
      });
      return option;
    },
    loadData: function(){
      // get data from server using API and set to vehicleTypeOptions
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.loadData();
  }
}
```

**Template snippet:**

```
<Pass v-for="vehicleType in VehicleTypes" v-bind:key="vehicleType" :temp="getVehicleData(vehicleType)">
  <div slot-scope="{temp}">
    <div class="pannel">
        <h6>{{ vehicleType }}</h6>
        <p v-if="temp">
          Cost per mile: <strong>${{ temp.costPerMile }}</strong>, 
          Cost per hour: <strong>${{ temp.costPerHour }}</strong>, 
          Cost per day: <strong>${{ temp.costPerDay }}</strong>
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</Pass>
```

Comment: This approach also uses scoped slots but is less verbose: https://dev.to/loilo/an-approach-to-vuejs-template-variables-5aik

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is impossible in the current version :(

In your example you can make a computed with calculated values and use it.

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="vehicleType, idx in vehicleTypes" :key="vehicleType">
    <h3>{{ vehicleType }}</h3>
    <div v-if="vtData[idx]">
     {{ vtData[idx].costPerMile }}<br>
     {{ vtData[idx].costPerHour }}<br>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

...

computed: {
  vtData() {
    return this.vehicleTypes.map(vt => this.getVehicleTypeData(vt));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Fernando Cesar already mentioned, there is undocumented feature `:set`, just a snippet and some links

```js
<ul>
  <li v-for="vehicleType in vehicleTypes" 
    :key="vehicleType"
    :set="vtd = getVehicleTypeData(vehicleType)"
  >
    <h3>{{ vehicleType }}</h3>
    <div v-if="vtd">
     {{ vtd.costPerMile }}<br>
     {{ vtd.costPerHour }}<br>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/1172#issuecomment-1035369827
https://dev.to/pbastowski/comment/7fc9

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is a reliable strategy:

```
<template>
  <div :style="{ opacity: 0, position: 'absolute' }">{{ variable = -Infinity }}</div>
  {{ variable }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted () {
    // The variable is actually added to the component.
    console.log (this.variable)
  }
}
</script>
```

There's probably a way to define variables in template loops also.